# Get last second of a date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the last second of a date in MySql 5.1. For example, my table has a column "date". I want to set another datetime column with the last second of date.

Something like:

```
update <TABLE>
set datetime = DATETIME(YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date), 23,59,59)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl SET datetime = DATE(date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
```